# SAS Macro outputting ODS HTML: Update Results Viewer

Tags: sas

I'm trying to call a macro called 'outputCrosstabs' which calls a PROC TABULATE and writes a HTML file to disk. I would also like to see the output in the results viewer as the ODS HTML is being created, however the Results Viewer only seems to update when the macro is finished. I don't have any ODS HTML CLOSE statements in the 'outputCrosstabs' macro.

```
ods html newfile=proc; *BYGROUP, PAGE, OUTPUT;
dm 'log; autoscroll 1';
data _null_ ;
   %runtheloop;
run ;

%macro runtheloop;
   %do i = 1 %to 2;
    %do j = 1 %to 2;
    DM 'log; clear;';
    %outputCrosstabs(&i,&j);
    %end;
   %end;
%mend;
```

How can I get the html in the Results Viewer to update as the macro is being executed so I can see the output as it's being generated instead of at the end? Is there an equivalent to Application.DoEvents() in C# or anything like that to get the UI to update?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the file out to an external HTML file(s) (rather than the SAS work directory one), and then monitor that with your favorite web browser.  I don't believe there's a way to do it directly in the SAS Results window, without closing/opening the file or running the program in sections, which is harder with a macro like that.